# Delphi XE3 stringgrid fixed cell click event doesn't fire

Tags: delphi, click, stringgrid

I have a StringGrid component in Delphi. I would like to catch when user clicks to the fixed cells (header).

When I bound `FixedCellClick` event to the grid, event can only detects the click using the left button of the mouse. If I try that with the right button, nothing happens.

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1FixedCellClick(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('');
end;
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, the `Click` events are typically associated with left-mouse button actions.  To handle mouse button events more generally the `Mouse` events are more useful.

In this case you can use the **OnMouseButtonDown** event.

**NOTE:**  This does not *exactly* correspond to a "click" since it occurs in response to the initial mouse down event, rather than reliably responding to a mouse-down-followed-by-a-mouse-up in the same region of a control.

However, it is often good enough.

The **OnMouseButtonDown** event includes a parameter that identifies the `Button` involved and the mouse `X` and `Y` positions.  It also include a `ShiftState` to detect Ctrl and/or Shift key states during the event (if relevant).

You can use these to detect a right-mouse button being pressed in your fixed rows/columns:

```
procedure TfrmMain.StringGrid1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
                                        Button: TMouseButton;
                                        Shift: TShiftState;
                                        X, Y: Integer);
var
  grid: TStringGrid;
  col, row: Integer;
  fixedCol, fixedRow: Boolean;
begin
  grid := Sender as TStringGrid;

  if Button = mbRight then
  begin
    grid.MouseToCell(X, Y, col, row);

    fixedCol := col < grid.FixedCols;
    fixedRow := row < grid.FixedRows;

    if   (fixedCol and fixedRow) then
      // Right-click in "header hub"

    else if fixedRow then
      // Right-click in a "column header"

    else if fixedCol then
      // Right-click in a "row header"

    else
      // Right-click in a non-fixed cell
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

`TStringGrid` is hard-coded to fire the `OnFixedCellClick` event only for left button clicks.  There is no event for right button clicks.  You would have to either modify `TStringGrid`'s source code, or else derive a custom component from `TStringGrid` so you can override the virtual `MouseUp()` method.